# Comment layout not readable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

As you can see in the screenshot below, the current `line-height` of `17px` is too low. After a try with firebug, I'd suggest to use a minimum `line-height: 20px;`.

*But* `line-height` *must not* have a unit. It's just a multiplication factor of the font size... (currently set for this definition: `tr.comment > td` in all.css acc. to firebug). I'd suggest to set it to `1.5`. You could also reduce the top/bottom padding for `a.comment-user.owner` (which currently overwrites `a.comment-user` for some reason).

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion. I agree with the line-height issue, especially WP site tends to have a lot of code blocks in comments. I have changed it to 1.5em as you suggested. The change will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Thanks. Btw: `line-height` has no unit.